# How to display the next page number automatically in Datatables pagination in place of ellipses

Tags: datatables

My pagination having total 64 pages, when I am clicking on page 5 I want that page 6 button is displayed automatically in UI. As of now its showing ellipses after page 5.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid displaying ellipses with [`full_numbers_no_ellipses`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/full_numbers_no_ellipses) or [`simple_numbers_no_ellipses`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses) pagination plug-ins.

See [jQuery DataTables: Pagination without ellipses](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-pagination-without-ellipses/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you should see the page number either side of the page you are on - so if your page is 5, you should see buttons for 4 and 6 (see example [here](http://live.datatables.net/sigesexa/1/edit)). You can use the [pagingType](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) option for different options on how the page numbers are displayed.